# nodejs, http, legacy servers, and "HPE_UNEXPECTED_CONTENT_LENGTH"

Tags: node.js, http, node-request

Running a simple http request in nodejs for web crawling purposes.

Unfortunately, one website we're trying to crawl is configured such that it has the Content-Length header **twice**.

This is throwing an error on nodejs:

```
Error: Parse Error
   at Error (native)
   at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:363:20)
   at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
   at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
   at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
   at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
   at TCP.onread (net.js:548:20) bytesParsed: 239, code:'HPE_UNEXPECTED_CONTENT_LENGTH' },
  isOperational: true,
  bytesParsed: 239,
  code: 'HPE_UNEXPECTED_CONTENT_LENGTH'
```

I'm trying to find a workaround that doesn't involve downgrading my nodejs server... Any ideas?